# Questions about a CTAT circuit

Tags: circuit-design, analog, basic

Please refer to the following CTAT circuit
[image]

source: https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-14

The following notations are used:

VR1 - voltage across resistor R1

VR2 - voltage across resistor R2

VQ1B - voltage at Q1 base

VQ2B - voltage at Q2 base

VQ1C - voltage at Q1 collector

VQ2C - voltage at Q2 collector

VQ2BE - base-emitter voltage of Q2

The followings are my understanding about this circuit:

(1) VR2 is PTAT

(2) VR1 is an amplified VR2, also it is PTAT

(3) VQ2BE is CTAT

(4) VQ2B is ZTAT

(5) The objective of this circuit is to deliver a ZTAT VOUT and VBG.

Now my questions are:

(1) Given VQ2B is ZTAT, how can one ensure VQ1C, VQ2C, VOUT are also ZTAT?

(2) Is the purpose of the opamp to ensure that VQ1C and VQ2C are the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you consider base current as being negligible, VOUT * R6/(R5+R6) = VQ2B. So, if VQ2B is ZTAT, VOUT will be ZTAT because the resistor ratio is a constant. VQ1C = VQ2C but both are not ZTAT. They reduce with temperature.
2. The purpose of the opamp is to ensure that IC1 = IC2 by ensuring that VQ1C = VQ2C